# find if one column contains another column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

anyone know to how to create a query to find out if the data in one column contains (like function) of another column?

For example

```
ID||First_Name || Last_Name
------------------------
1 ||Matt       || Doe
------------------------
2 ||Smith      || John Doe
------------------------
3 ||John       || John Smith
```

find all rows where Last_name contains First_name. The answer is ID 3

thanks in advance

Comment: In Oracle, I'd try something like `Select * from TABLE where instr(first_name, last_name) >= 1;`.  And MySql has an `instr()` function that behaves the same way.

Comment: this worked great, I would vote for this answer if I could, thanks

Comment: I posted it as an answer.  Wasn't certain I had it right, so thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Select *
  from TABLE
 where instr(first_name, last_name) >= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from TABLE where last_name LIKE '%' + first_name + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE Last_Name LIKE '%'+First_Name+'%'
```

You could also use `INSTR()`, but take note, both methods perform full-table scans, a general no-no when dealing with high-performance MySQL.

Comment: with regard to performance, they may avoid a full table scan by putting an index on `(Last_Name, First_Name)`.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, I always thought that having a prefix and suffix wildcard, or just prefix, would ignore the index because it cannot use the first set of characters in the index, resulting in a full scan. Is this different when using a column as the LIKE query?

Comment: Yes, usually LIKE with a % at the start will not use the index because it cannot do an index scan to quickly narrow down to a subset of records. However, it's possible for Oracle to do a Full Index Scan which is often quicker than a Full Table Scan.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, that's interesting, thanks for sharing. Not too familiar with Oracle to be fair, in-fact, I had no idea the OP tagged Oracle until just now - must look more carefully in future :)